# Can't switch off functionality do not disturb

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, volume-control, do-not-disturb

I've activated the functionality do not disturb for 6 hours for my phone, so all the sounds were turned off. Then I switched off my phone while thr functionality was still on without switching it off. When i open it up again I found that do not disturb it's still on, i can't deactivate or activate it, the volumes seekbars look like when they are switched off by the functionality, but i can hear sounds, and I can't move the volumes level, apart from the multimedia one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an avent of some minutes, that starts and stops the do not disturb, after that everything will be ok